# TODOs in javascript files not showing up in Task list

Tags: javascript, eclipse, task

For some reason the TODO Tags i added to my .js files are not showing up inside the Tasks View. I've already made sure, that the "TODO" tag itsself is set under Task Tags for javascript but thei're still not showing up in the list. I've made a filter for the view to show all Tasks in the working set i'm using but nothing is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have your files in JavaScript Source Folders within a project and be running the JavaScript Validator Builder (or having it installed and automatic builds enabled).

Comment: There is anyway to show it without the javascript validator? i have thousands of js.. i can't enable it.

Answer (score 8):

nitind's answer is perfect. I would like to make it comprehensive.

Right click the project & select properties. In 'Builders' , select 'JavaScript Validator'.

Similarly, to parse tasks in HTML, CSS & XML files, goto Preferences->General->Editors->Structured Text Editors->Task Tags and click 'Enable searching for Task Tags'

NOTE: The answer is validated only in eclipse indigo (3.7.1)

Comment: When I go into 'Builders' in project properties, 'JavaScript Validator' is not one of the options.  The only thing I see is 'PyDev Builder'.  How do I add 'JavaScript Validator' as a Builder so that I can select it? I'm using Indigo Service Release 1.

Comment: From the project's Configure menu, choose to make it a JavaScript project.  This will let you set up source folders and install the JavaScript Validating builder.

Comment: My JavaScript files are part of a project which should not be converted to a JavaScript project. Isn't there any other way to set it up?